# Firebase Analyics Exclude website From Apps

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

We have an iOS and Android app connected to Firebase for analytics. We also have a website (just a landing page) also connected to firebase with google analyics. But now our analytics is based on iOS/Android and the Website. Since our website is just a dumb landing page this is really annoying in the analytics.

As you can see in the image below it states that we have 437 users in the last 30 days. This is incorrect since we only have +-40 people using our app, and Google Play and Apple App Store dashboards also do not sum up to 437 downloads.

So how can we exclude the website from these analytics?

[image]